# C++ overload the + operator of a class so you can add a different class to that class and get a third class

Tags: c++

So I'm just playing around but I would like to see if I can overload the + operator of a class to allow it to not add two of itself together, but add it to a second class and get a third class as a result.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class dog;
class cat;
class catdog;

class dog
{
    public:
    string name;
    int weight;
    string soundMakes;

    dog(string, int, string);

    catdog operator + (const cat&);
};

dog::dog(string inName, int inWeight, string inSound)
{
    name = inName;
    weight = inWeight;
    soundMakes = inSound;
}

catdog dog::operator + (const cat& inCat)
{
    catdog newBorn("Rottens", this -> weight + inCat.weight, "Wooeow");

    return newBorn;
}

class cat
{
public:
    string name;
    int weight;
    string soundMakes;

    cat(string, int, string);
};

cat::cat(string inName, int inWeight, string inSound)
{
    name = inName;
    weight = inWeight;
    soundMakes = inSound;
}

class catdog
{
    string name;
    int weight;
    string soundMakes;

    catdog(string, int, string);
};

catdog::catdog(string inName, int inWeight, string inSound)
{
    name = inName;
    weight = inWeight;
    soundMakes = inSound;
}

int main()
{
    dog rover("Rover", 20, "Woof");
    cat mittens("Mittens", 10, "Meow");

    catdog rottens = rover + mittens;

    cout << "I have a cat dog, his name is " << rottens.name << " and he weighs " << rottens.weight << endl;
}
```

I've been trying this but I keep getting problems with it not knowing what a cat is during the dogs operator + overload (or vice versa depending on the order). The exact error is class is imcomplete.

Is there anyway to accomplish what I'm tyring to do? I realise this example seems pretty stupid but I'm more going for if its possible to do the concept.

Comment: How about non-member `operator+`?

Comment: You can forward declare the classes used by the dog declaration. Just add `class cat; class catdog;` before `dog`, and it will know that the other classes exist. (And also terminate each class with a `;`).

Comment: Yea I actually typed that all from scratch rather than copy code I was working on, realised after I submitted that I forgot the terminating ; on the classes. >.<

Comment: I tried to forward declare the classes but I still get errors telling me invalid use of incomplete class.

Answer (score 1):

You may use non-member `operator+` instead. Place it after all 3 classes so that it can see them all as complete type.

```
catdog operator + (const dog& inDog, const cat& inCat)
{
    catdog newBorn("Rottens", inDog.weight + inCat.weight, "Wooeow");

    return newBorn;
}
```

Full code and demo:

- https://godbolt.org/g/1Yoq9D
- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6bc0182103fe414

Comment: Looks good, is there any disadvantage of having an operator overload as a non member of its class?

Comment: @Mowen Non-member operator cannot access private member of the classes. But it can be managed by using [friend declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend).